# MySql Schedule event

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks

I want to insert data in a table at the beginning of every month, I though to use mysql event. But someone told me that if I miss that event (Mean if my server is down in scheduled date/time then mysql will no rerun that event after getting online, not sure) then mysql will not rerun it again.

So I have created a table celled `event_balance` where event will be logged. Then I created a event called `balance_update_check` which will run every hour and check if event was executed for this month, if not then it will call a procedure which will create rows for this month and then update table  `event_balance` with `event_type` and `date`.

But I am not satisfied with this, please check my codes and tell me is it OK? if possible provide a better solution. Thanks for you time.

**Event balance_update_check**

```
CREATE
    EVENT `balance_update_check`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Hour
    DO BEGIN
        set @check_if_cont_doc:= (SELECT count(*) FROM event_balance WHERE event_type = 'doctor_contract' and monthname(event_balance.date) = monthname(CURDATE()));        

        set @check_if_cont_other:= (SELECT count(*) FROM event_balance WHERE event_type = 'other_contract' and monthname(event_balance.date) = monthname(CURDATE()));

        IF (@check_if_cont_doc = 0) Then
            call proc_leave_bal_doc_cont();
            Insert into event_balance (event_type,`date`) values('doctor_contract',CURDATE())       
        END IF;     

        IF (@check_if_cont_other = 0) Then
            call proc_leave_bal_other_cont();
            Insert into event_balance (event_type,`date`) values('other_contract',CURDATE())        
        END IF;
END //
```

Comment: I have a solution here but not really relevant. Are you using a system that has monthly dues?

Comment: no, but any example of event scheduled monthly will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure that the event_scheduler is set to ON in your my.cnf file. Head over to your my.cnf file (or my.ini file if you are using Windows) and either comment out the `event_scheduler=DISABLED` or set `event_scheduler=ON`. Then restart. This is make sure that your events run after a server reboot. There is some more info about it here:dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events-configuration.html